# Bundle several cabinet files together? (for Windows Mobile)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, compact-framework, cab

I am writing application for Windows Mobile 6.5, and for application to run, I have to install `sqlce.wce5.armv4i.cab` and `NETCFv35.wm.armv4i.cab` files on the end device.

Is there someway that I can combine and bundle those two cabinet files together with my application cabinet file? I want to create a single install process, which would install each file sequentially one after another (when I start bundled cabinet file)?

Is it possible? Or what is the easier solution to create more automated installation of required packages (such as for SQL Server CE)?

--
I am able to create cab file with other two cab files in it, but how can I make them execute right after I finish installing cab file that contains them? Right now it just extract them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am right you are looking for Multicab Installation.

WM already comes with an example on this. Here is a [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158796.aspx).

The sample can be found on your PC at C:\Program Files\Windows Mobile 6.5.3 DTK\Samples\Common\CPP\Win32\multicabinstall

Answer (score 0):

From what I have learned in the past, that can't really be done.

When I learned this long ago (back on some other site before SO came along), I was bummed and thought this was the dumbest thing ever.

Now, I keep those two files (plus another I use called `NETCFv35.Messages.EN.wm.cab`) on the same Network folder that my installing CAB file is located on.

Also, I install those files onto each device's Flash Drive, that way if one of our employees forgets to charge the battery and the device resets, I can quickly get the old WM5 device's CF upgraded to v35 and and get sqlce running.

### Note:

Things may have changed! Someone may have learned a way to combine these CAB files into your project's cab file.

If you can do that, just keep in mind that every time you go to update your application, instead of your CAB file being 200k, it is going to have to be the combined size of all of the CABs.

You might run out of room!

Also, if one of your CAB files is going to be the `NETCFv35.wm.armv4i.cab` (at 2,644 KB), the device's OS has to reboot after installation. That would likely cause your program's CAB file to fail.

There may be a way around that, but not that I've learned.

Comment: Yes, combining these MS CABs into one cab is no good idea. They use there own setup.dll with additional install changes. But the mentioned MS article about installing several at once does not merge the cabs. Instead they are extracted from another cab and then installed one by one using wceload.exe.